# Is iCloud sharing safe?

Tags: icloud, sharing

Someone offered to share their account with me so I could get a couple games for free.

If I use their account could they access mine somehow? I'm worried about them accessing my personal stuff that I have on my iCloud.
Also they gave me an iCloud email.. can you even use a iCloud email for iTunes?

Comment: This sounds kinda sketchy...

Comment: Don't do it. Otherwise you risk being accused of things later by your friend.

Answer (score 2):

I would resist the temptation, & would advise them to not make this kind of offer in future.

To say this is foolhardy barely begins to cover it.

Though you having their Apple ID details isn't directly harmful to you, it is not true for them. You would have total access to **their** data.

They are not giving you a couple of games for free, they are handing you the keys to their entire private life.

The only direct harm it would cause you is that should they change their password at any later date, you will never be able to update or reinstall any of the items that used their ID.

..and that's apart from the fact that you & they would be breaking the terms of your license agreement & basically stealing the software.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you do not enable *any* iCloud services, the other user is unable to access your data.

However, the iTunes Store sometimes locks to an account to prevent things like this and will not let you return to your normal account for a period of 90 days.

Also, by sharing apps when you are not supposed to, you are technically stealing a software license, which is *technically illegal*. You're also cutting into the developer's budget, which is a whole other problem entirely.

Comment: What happens if it locks my out of my original account for 90 days? Will I still be able to access my music/apps I already have on my phone?

Comment: @user224554 yes but you will not be able to download more that you already purchased on your account and may not even be able to update apps on your phone already purchased with your own account